# MariaDB AUTO_INCREMENT Jump to Max (unsigned) int

Tags: mysql, mariadb

**EDIT:** *it was a bug in or application*

**What could cause the auto_increment value to jump up billions of values to strike max int?**

Our core table uses an `int unsigned auto_increment` primary key column. Today it skipped every value all the way up to 4294967295.

I was able to resolve this by deleting the offensive row and running

```
ALTER TABLE [table] AUTO_INCREMENT = [new value];
```

but I cannot explain how or why it happened.

Our environment is MariaDB 10.2.27 under PHP/Apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any INSERT can specify a high value, and this will implicitly advance the next auto-increment value. In other words, an auto-increment for a table will never be less than the largest value currently inserted in the table, and any client can override the auto-increment mechanism simply by specifying a value in an INSERT.

Demo:

```
mysql> create table mytable (id int unsigned auto_increment primary key);

mysql> insert into mytable (id) values (DEFAULT);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

That should have inserted id value 1, so the next AI will be 2:

```
mysql> show create table mytable\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: mytable
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Now I specify a large value, and the AI is updated accordingly:

```
mysql> insert into mytable (id) values(1000000000);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> show create table mytable\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: mytable
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1000000001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Note a value greater than the max unsigned int value 2<sup>32</sup>-1 will be truncated to that value.

```
mysql> insert into mytable (id) values(1000000000000);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table mytable\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: mytable
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4294967295 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

So *someone* must have inserted a large value. Any value larger than 4294967295 will be truncated to 4294967295, and then subsequent inserts that try to use the AI sequence will fail.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response.  I understand the effect you describe, but am not aware of any code path (in our app) that would allow anything to specify a value for this column to trigger this effect.

Comment: Either it's in your app, or someone did an insert manually using a mysql client. Or an ALTER TABLE to manually set the AI value.

Comment: Something else I've learned is failed `INSERT`s can cause skipped values, but not to this degree.

Comment: Reality is I found an offending codepath in our code.